How to Send Notifications Using sendMulticast with Token Chunking in kreait/laravel-firebase?
I'm using the kreait/laravel-firebase package to send push notifications to a large number of users. Since I need to send notifications to a large number of device tokens, I'm trying to use the sendMulticast method and chunk the tokens to respect the Firebase limit of 500 tokens per request.
$all_data = array_chunk($recipients, 500); // Split tokens into chunks of 500

foreach ($all_data as $deviceTokens) {
    $message = CloudMessage::new()
        ->withNotification($notification)
        ->withData([
            'extra_data' => 'some_data',
        ]);

    // Send the message to the chunk of tokens
    $result = $messaging->sendMulticast($message, $deviceTokens);
    dd($result); // Check the result for each batch
}

Showing Bellow Errors :
#message: "Operation is not implemented, or supported, or enabled."
    #code: 501
    #file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\sajida-fieldforce\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Exception\Messaging\MessagingError.php"
    #line: 22
    #errors: array:1 [▼
      "error" => array:3 [▼
        "code" => 501
        "message" => "Operation is not implemented, or supported, or enabled."
        "status" => "UNIMPLEMENTED"
      ]
    ]


You might want to call sendAll instead. See the note on https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/blob/7.x/docs/cloud-messaging.rst#send-messages-in-batches

Package maintainer here 
You are using an old version of the package that still uses the FCM APIs that have been deprecated/shut down in the meantime. Please upgrade to to an at least 7.x version of the package to make it work again.
Also, in the latest release, there's no need to chunk the  tokens since all messages are sent asynchronously one by one. You can still do it in (the admittedly unlikely ) case you have so many tokens that you run into memory issues.
